# display the value of bool in swift

Tags: swift, boolean, println

I would like to print the result of the bool value
When I do it I have "true" instead the amount.
I know it probably sounds really stupid but I'm just getting started with swift

```
var monthsWeek:Int?
var hoursWageHours:Double = 14.47
let months4WeeksHours:Double = 156.00
let months5WeeksHours:Double = 195.00
var normalpay:Double = 0
let months5weeks:Bool = true
let months4weeks:Bool = true

if months5weeks {

normalpay = hoursWageHours * months5WeeksHours

if months4weeks {

    normalpay = hoursWageHours * months4WeeksHours
}
}
```

or woud that make more sence even if didnt print the result still

```
var monthsWeek:Int?
var hoursWageHours:Double = 14.47
let months4WeeksHours:Double = 156.00
let months5WeeksHours:Double = 195.00
var normalpay:Double = 0


if monthsWeek == 195 {

normalpay = hoursWageHours * months5WeeksHours

if monthsWeek == 4 {

    normalpay = hoursWageHours * months4WeeksHours
}

}
```

monthsWeek = 4

Comment: Just use the function `print` ?

Comment: A boolean variable can be either `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A boolean variable can take only 2 values (true or false).
So it is logical that when you print it you have true or false.

Answer (score 4):

I came here looking for an actual print of a bool. It turns out you can do this:

```
var a_bool = false
print("a_bool is ")
println(a_bool)
```

And you can do this with ints:

```
var a_int = 42
println("This is an int " + String(a_int))
```

You can't do this with bools though. However you can do:

```
println("This is a bool " + String(stringInterpolationSegment: a_bool))
```

This is the closet I can come up with for something like this:

```
println("a_bool is ", a_bool) // does not work 
println("a_bool is " + a_bool) // also does not work
```

Later on, I learned you can use \(variable) embedding like this:

println("This is an int \(a_int)")

Comment: While the OP's question is fairly bad this answer is the one I was after when I reached this question so thanks for spending the time to answer the question the OP's title indicates they wanted to know the answer to! :)